# asp.net repeater "the server tag is not well formed"

Tags: asp.net, .net, repeater

Before marking me down, or flagging as a duplicate I have looked and cannot find my answer on here although there are similar issues - most are relating to javascript calls on asp.net controls.  This is not that.

I am trying to provide an id to a checkbox in a repeater based on the value that comes out of the datasource that is bound to the repeater.

I have had no trouble with elements that are not asp.net controls, however when it comes to providing an it to a checkbox like the example below I get the error

> Error creating control - rptPayments
>
> The server tag is not well formed.

This is how I am trying to name it at the moment

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="cbValidated_<%# Eval("ContactId")%>" />
```

I have seen that there are a number of questions out there for similar issues but typically they are for javascript \ OnClientClick(..) funcitons telling people to use single quotes.

if I try single quotes, I get a new error

> the ID property of a control can only be set using the ID attribute in the tag and a simple value. Example

I need this as a server side control so that I can loop through all the checkboxes on the click of a button to see which records have been validated or not, but need to link it with the contactId

Comment: That's not possible with Server controls. As soon as you add the `runat` attribute the control becomes a server control and you can't change its ID dynamically. Why you want to do this first of all?

Comment: I have a dataset of about 50 payments that need to be made, before they are made they need to be validated, and the database updated accordingly. Once the check box is checked and a bulk update button is pressed the code behind will go through each of the checkboxes looking for the id of the payment and then update the record accordingly.  if its not possible this way by naming the id, I may as well drop the repeater and then build it all the time the page is loaded.

Comment: No Wait wait :) Changing the ID is not possible that way but you can obviously check whether they are checked or not and then proceed. Don't drop the control itself.

Comment: how best should I do this then? because I don't want to check via `request.form(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that your bulk-update button is present outside the repeater. In that case you will have you to loop through the repeater items and proceed like this:-

```
protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (RepeaterItem item in MyRepeater.Items)
    {
        CheckBox cbValidated = item.FindControl("cbValidated") as CheckBox;
        if (chkTest.Checked)
        {
            //Do Stuff (You can save some custom values in a list and finally update all)
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

As mentioned in the comment the correct way to do this is to store the id of the record is in a hidden variable rather than setting it to the `ID` of a control (which is not possible anyways). So simply add one Hidden field like this:-

```
<ItemTemplate>
   <asp:CheckBox ID="cbValidated" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("foo") %>' />
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Here, `ID` is the name of the column which will map to your record. Then simply find this value if user has checked the checkbox like this:-

```
//Rest code same as mentioned above
if (chkTest.Checked)
{
    HiddenField hdnID = item.FindControl("hdnID") as HiddenField;
    string id = hdnID.Value; //use this id for your logic. 
}
```

Comment: thats similar to how I was going to get getting checking to see if the control is checked, however still doesn't give me the id of the contactId to tie it back to the right account

Comment: @SimonPrice - Hey why you interested in `Id` of the checkbox? You should be storing the id for that record in some hidden control and when that checkbox is checked reading the value from hidden control.

Comment: if i have a checkbox with an id of say cb_repeater1_0 how would that then tie back to record 123454. I was using the id of the record in the checkbox id in order to ensure i am validating the right information.

Comment: @SimonPrice - Yeah got it but you will have to store that `id` somewhere right? Simply use a Hidden Field control. Please check my update.

Comment: @SimonPrice - Glad it helped you :)